# Getting bounding boxes of characters from PDF

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I've been hacking away at this for a couple of days now, but haven't been able to find a solution that is satisfactory. Essentially, my goal is to find the bounding boxes of characters from PDF to eventually use as training data for an OCR system. This means I need clear and consistent bounding box extraction from generated PDFs (like those at arxiv which actually have text information in them, hence the ability to highlight with cursor). I've been mainly working with python and PDFMiner.

Most of the solutions I've seen are for now lower level than lines of text, and the issue I had there was that PDFs had such varying structures that this wasn't even reliable. I've been able to get bounding boxes of characters through html using pdftotext, but the boxes were mis-sized, most often cutting off the tail ends of characters which are crucial to OCR training.

Thanks!

Comment: not familiar with PDFMiner, but many a time bounding boxes are not accurate. Would you be able to get the actual glyph boundaries, if yes, then they would be more accurate.

Comment: @bulbus Do you know of any methods for being able to extract glyph boundaries?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?